# Asp.Net MVC 5 FileResult always download file with ANSI encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, asp.net-mvc-5, fileresult

I have this part of code

```
Response.Charset = _encodingcode;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", _encodingcode);
Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(_encodingcode);
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(_encodingcode);
Response.ContentType = mimeType;                     

return File(_filedata, mimeType, $"{id}{_extension}");
```

But always when download the file the notepad's encoding is ANSI

Comment: [just check this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320674/asp-net-mvc-how-to-set-encoding-when-returning-fileresult)

Comment: if you look up i have arleady tried to use Response.Charset. Still notepad++ open file with the same encding for all files

Comment: See if any of the links help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679656/asp-net-excel-export-encoding-problem , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376602/%C3%AF-character-utf-8-bom-in-middle-of-asp-net-response-due-to-httpresponse-tran, https://github.com/SmallAnts/Smart/blob/a1e51221a690788aeb6f950b0f683c6cf5f2acc6/Src/Framework/Smart.Web.Mvc.Shared/ControllerBase.cs#L129

Comment: @GomuGomuNoRocket be specific about what `_filedata` is

Comment: protected internal virtual FileContentResult File(byte[] fileContents, string contentType, string fileDownloadName);

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani i tried everything that you suggested. But ALWAYS AND ALWAYS the notepad open the file with ANSI as UTF-8

Comment: Try with notepad++ instead of just notepad

Comment: You can add a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) to the start of a text file to explicitly define it as UTF-8. If you don't, software like Notepad simply don't explicitly know what encoding a text file is because text files dont have any structure to allow it to, it's simply an unstructured stream of bytes that's inferred to be one encoding or another by its contents.

Comment: @GomuGomuNoRocket, how do you set _filedata?

Comment: Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8; 
     HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(encoding.EncodingName)

Comment: your code is so incomplete what   is the  value of   _encodingcode; Response.Charset = _encodingcode;

Comment: use this  for utf8  Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;

Answer (score 0):

Notepad receives only _filedata bytes which are saved to disk as file with name specified in 3rd parameter, but neither mimeType nor any element of response header or body, that why specifying encoding has no effect.

You can give a hint to Notepad about some encodings by adding Byte Order Mark (BOM) at the beginning of you bytes stream:

- For UTF-8 - 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF
- For UTF-16/32 - 0xFF, 0xFE

Apart from that, there is no way to tell Notepad what encoding it should use.

Answer (score 0):

By default every encoding is ANSI if you provide improper text in encoding it goes as ANSI.
Right way to change use

```
Context.Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
```

If you want utf8 do this

```
 Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
     StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Encoding.html", false, encoding);

     writer.WriteLine("<html><head>");

     // Write charset attribute to the html file.
     // The value of charset is returned by the WebName property.
     writer.WriteLine("<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=" +
                           encoding.WebName +"\">");

         writer.WriteLine("</head><body>");
     writer.WriteLine("<p>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(encoding.EncodingName) + "</p>");
     writer.WriteLine("</body></html>");
     writer.Flush();
     writer.Close();
```